# Support for TFS workspaces in .NET Core

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We have a large amount of legacy code that uses the old "TFS Client Object Model" via the old framework assemblies.  We are porting all our tooling to .NET latest i.e. the new REST client libraries.

Our tools usually operate in the following way:

- get source,
- perform an operation e.g. manipulate project files,
- check in any resulting changes.

The changes are tracked by the Workspace class. This class wraps all the logic for mapping local paths to remote and knowing if files have changed and what the change type is (add vs edit).

The new REST client libraries don't support workspaces. There is nothing in the new libraries that manages the state locally compared to remotely.

TF.exe still supports workspaces. TF.exe is a framework app that references the old client libraries.

The first part of this question is:

What is the plan regarding TF.exe?

The old client libraries are no longer being maintained and the advice is to move code to the REST client libraries.  Will TF.exe be ported?  Will workspaces be implemented at that point in a .NET Core library?  Or will they be deprecated in general?

The second part is:

What are folks who need check-in/check-out automation in .NET Core doing now?

Wrapping TF.exe?

Rolling their own workspace replacement code?  How are folks translating between local and remote paths during change detection?  How are folks working out if items exist server side or not i.e. is a change an add or an edit?  How are merges handled?

I can't seem to find many examples of programmatic check-in/check-out with change detection. I've searched high and low for references to code containing the types I think would be involved e.g. TfvcChangeset, TfvcChange, ItemContent. The only code I can find is the REST client library samples. The samples only contain the most basic examples e.g. how to send up the addition of a new file. I can't find anything that demonstrates how do proper change detection. The GitHub project for the samples is currently read-only and hasn't been touched in some time.

At the moment, I'm trying to decide if I have to re-invent workspaces myself, or wrap TF.exe, or do something else to maintain the functionality I had before with the old client libraries?

Comment: You're largely on point with your assumptions. Something you may not have considered is stepping back and examining what you're doing programmatically and finding a solution that doesn't involve needing automation to manipulate version control. It may not be possible, but it also may be as simple as rethinking some of your teams' processes and workflows.

Comment: Use cases for automation are manipulating project files e.g. changing target framework, build configurations in bulk, adjusting warning levels and generating boiler plate code.  We have hundreds of projects across tens of solutions and we try not to do anything in bulk manually if we can automate it.  It would have been nice if whoever downvoted my question bothered to state why.

Comment: Aside: I have also had downvotes without explanations. It feels rude and unhelpful. How is someone going to improve without knowing the criticism?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Azure DevOps supports both TFVC and git repositories but Microsoft is clearly moving away from supporting TFVC. You should consider migrating from TFVC to git. Expect that at some point TFVC will be removed from Azure DevOps.

Workspaces are specific to TFVC and to the client. The old object model supported client side and server side objects. The [Azure DevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) is an API for the server side only. There are APIs for TFVC repos and those APIs work against the state of the repo on the server, not what a specific local workspace may have.

Most of the functionality of `tf.exe` is concerned with working with TFVC. Most developers are using git repos and don't use `tf`.

You can automate changes with git.

Comment: Sadly I have to agree with this and it would be safe to say > 60% of  .net core devs who used TFVC now use Git. I loved the old TFVC, however this answer is correct you'll need to upgrade sooner or later. Also the Technical Fellow behind Visual Source Safe and TFS: Brian Harry is not active at Microsoft anymore: https://adamcogan.com/2018/04/06/farewell-brian-harry-father-microsoft-source-control/

Comment: *Expect that at some point TFVC will be removed from Azure DevOps.* No, don't expect that. TFVC is considered feature complete and is no longer receiving investment in developing new features, but it is not being removed at any point in the foreseeable future.

Comment: @DanielMann It sounds like you are providing Microsoft's public position -- which is useful to a degree. TFVC is increasingly difficult to use with current tools and processes. Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio for Mac don't support TFVC. YAML builds are not supported with TFVC. These are not "new features" for TFVC; these are other Microsoft tools eschewing supporting TFVC. With this trend there is a point in the future where TFVC will be essentially unusable. Useless things tend to be removed. That is foreseeable.

Comment: I'm providing Microsoft's position along with my knowledge as a consultant that works extensively within the devops space with massive enterprises that still use TFVC and are major Microsoft customers. Microsoft would not remove a feature used by some of their largest customers without giving a public deprecation warning **years** in advance. There's nothing wrong with migrating to Git if you want the latest and greatest features. There's also nothing wrong with staying on TFVC if it fits your team's workflow and isn't impeding your work.

Comment: That said, I do typically start with a recommendation to investigate the feasibility of migrating to Git. However, auditing and regulatory requirements, major workflow differences, training, external tooling integration, etc all can prevent significant barriers to Git adoption, especially on large, enterprise codebases with years if not decades of history.

Comment: I completely agree that is it very difficult for some organizations to migrate away from TFVC. I also completely agree that Microsoft will give a public deprecation warning before removing TFVC.